# Thorough and Through

Tags: meaning

I rather like to use the word ***thorough***, but was recently informed by a reviewer that it was "archaic". Indeed, Merriam-Webster [lists it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thorough) first as an archaic spelling of ***through***, with the familiar definition only as a secondary one.

Is this specific to American spellings, or is this a general trend?
What should I use instead?
Saying "painstakingly" might be all right, but it seems odd to say "He was very painstaking.".

Comment: Dictionary meanings are listed chronologically, not by current popularity. The fact that MW gives an archaic meaning of _thorough_ first is thus no black mark against the validity or currency of subsequent definitions it gives.

Comment: @ John: Unless you'd used the word adverbially (as in, *"He looked **thorough** the window"*) I suggest your "reviewer" is in the wrong job. But note that *painstakingly, exhaustively, completely*, etc., would be replaceable by ***thoroughly***, not *thorough*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, the reviewer seems to be in error. What I intended to say was that I could easily imagine replacements for Thoroughly, but not for thorough itself.

Comment: Perhaps *painstaking, exhaustive, complete, etc.?* :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The archaic definition you are referring to only applies to the use of *thorough* as an adverb or preposition.  Look down a bit further (to the 3rd entry) and you'll see that *thorough* is the familiar adjective you know and love:

> **thor·ough** *adjective* \ˈthər-(ˌ)ō, sometimes ˈthȯr-; ˈthə-(ˌ)rō\
>
> Definition of THOROUGH
>   **1 :** carried through to completion : exhaustive <a thorough search>
>   **2
>   a :** marked by full detail <a thorough description>
>   **b :** careful about detail : painstaking <a thorough scholar>
>   **c :** complete in all respects <thorough pleasure>
>   **d :** having full mastery (as of an art) <a thorough musician>
>
> — thor·ough·ly *adverb*
>
> — thor·ough·ness *noun*

Comment: Thanks. Some other things the reviewer said indicated they may not have had the best grasp of English to begin with, so perhaps that's why.